# querysets in models with manytomany fields (Django)

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, django-queryset

My question is associated with making querysets on models that are interconnected across many to many fields.

context - an app that a student enters and has to rate his or her teachers. the questions the app shows the student have the following logic: each student must rate some teachers. Each teacher has different categories of questions associated with them ("intelligence", "respect", "empathy",etc.) and each of these categories has some questions associated with it.

The models are:

```
class Items(models.Model):
     item = models.TextField()
     def __str__(self):
          return self.item

class Categories(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
    items_associated  = models.ManyToManyField(Items)
    def __str__(self):
       return self.category

class Professors(models.Model):
    professor = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
    categories_assigned = models.ManyToManyField(Categories)
    def __str__(self):
       return self.professor

class Students(models.Model):
    student_logged = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
    professors_to_evaluate = models.ManyToManyField(Professors)
    def __str__(self):
       return self.student_logged
```

when a student enters the web has some associated teachers (model Students) these teachers in turn have some categories assigned (model Professors), these categories in turn have some questions associated (model Categories). **I want to store in a dictionary these questions that are in the model Items.** How can I do it?

I've tried to filter and __in but I can't get it.

Many thanks and thank you for the wisdom

Comment: Do you want all of the items that a `Students` object has access to? Just clarifying cause it's a bit unclear what the end result you want is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly suggest you use the `related_name` attribute. I've added `_x` to the related names to make the query more obvious.

```
class Items(models.Model):
     item = models.TextField()
     def __str__(self):
          return self.item

class Categories(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
    items_associated  = models.ManyToManyField(Items, related_name='category_x')
    def __str__(self):
       return self.category

class Professors(models.Model):
    professor = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
    categories_assigned = models.ManyToManyField(Categories, related_name='professor_x')
    def __str__(self):
       return self.professor

class Students(models.Model):
    student_logged = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
    professors_to_evaluate = models.ManyToManyField(Professors, related_name='student_x')
    def __str__(self):
       return self.student_logged

items_for_student = Items.objects.filter(category_x__professor_x__student_x=student)
```

But also the naming conventions you are using for the fields are a bit quirky. I've used best practices below so you can see what that would look like.

1. Don't have a field with the same name as the model
2. Models should be singular (with rare exceptions)
3. ManyToMany or ForeignKey relations should share the name of the model to make querying self document.

With those rules here is what the best practice looks like.

```
class Item(models.Model):
     name = models.TextField()
     def __str__(self):
          return self.name

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, related_name='categories')
    def __str__(self):
       return self.name

class Professor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='professors')
    def __str__(self):
       return self.name

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
    professors = models.ManyToManyField(Professor, related_names='students')
    def __str__(self):
       return self.name
```

And with that structure the query would look like:

```
items = Item.objects.filter(categories__professors__students=student)
```

Also note that the above query will be *very* expensive to run on a database as it would evaluate to 3 joins.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. About what you say the query will be very expensive, what other alternatives could make the search less expensive?

Comment: @Ale there's not a whole lot you can do without changing the schema to denormalize your data. You could add indexes to you models which will speed it up to an extent. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.index_together

Comment: Thank you for your enormous help. when you say " changing the schema to denormalize your data" that means for example to join in the same model the models "Category" and "Item". What are the pros and cons of this(join models)?